# How to change the style of a CSS class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

for example, I have some Html code like this

```
<div class="abc"></div>
```

with a css stylesheet like this

```
.abc{display:none}
```

Now I would like to change the style of css class `abc` to `display:block`, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Would you like to change really property and value of the CSS class or just change class applied to your HTML element ?

In this case, with jQuery for example, you just have to do :

```
$('div').removeClass('abc').addClass('cba');
```

This will remove the 'abc' class currently attached to your div element and set the 'cba' class for this element.

Your 'cba' class is defined as :

```
.cba{display: block}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use simple action below

```
$(".abc").show(); // to display block on css
$(".abc").hide(); // to display none on css
```

Here full code to implement your question

```
<!--html code-->
<div class="abc">Hello World</div>

<!--stlyling-->
<style>
    .abc{display:none}
</style>

<!--script-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".abc").show();
    });
</script>
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 2):

For all the people saying `document.getElementsByClassName('abc').style.display = 'block';` works...


How it should be:

```js
let e = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
for(i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
  e[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.abc{display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="abc">HI!</div>
<div class="abc">You can see me!</div>
```

`document.getElementsByClassName('abc').style.display = 'block';` method:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('abc').style.display = 'block';
```

```css
.abc{display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="abc">HI!</div>
<div class="abc">You can see me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your element in the DOM and use `el.classList.remove("abc")` to remove the `.abc` class.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

How to find the element?

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

> import jquery library using
>
> `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>`
>
> Use simple jquery to hide or show

```
$(".abc").hide();//for display none
$(".abc").show();//for display block
```

Comment: The second method doesn't work. Could be a small mistake or you forgot the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> IF you have one '.abc' class :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].style.display = "block";
```

> IF you have more of one '.abc' class :

```
var len = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
for(i = 0; i < len.length; i++){
  len[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Nope! Gotta use that `for` loop for this method!

Comment: That's not how you have it displayed. You never said use `[0]` or `[1]`!

Comment: Also, this is inefficient. You want to use a `for` loop for this if you're going all vanilla JS.